# How to make synchronized local caches in hazelcast with springboot

Tags: caching, hazelcast, distributed-system

I am building services that the load balancer direct the request to these services to make the system high available 24/7, each service has local cache, these caches must be synchronized to make maintain the data consistency, so that all services have the same data into its local cache so that no need for remote cache, and it will be better.

I am using hazelcast with springboot, the default cache is remote cache, a distributed cache, I don't want this approach.

I know there is another approach is called naer cache, but still it does not address my problem, I just want local-cache on each node and all data of local-caches are the same, Is this available in hazelcast? or I should looking for another technology?